# How can I access variable outside event click

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Hi everyone as title says I would like to achieve access to my variable called "Year" outside from my event.

Is that possible?

```
const ModifyYear = () =>
{
    const button = document.querySelector(".button");
    let Year = 2022;
    
    button.addEventListener("click", () =>
    {
        Year = 2023;
    })
    console.log(Year); //2022
}
```

Comment: The problem with your code is that you're forgetting that JavaScript events are asynchronous. When you execute `console.log()` the `click` event hasn't yet happened. What you want to do is not possible in the way you write it. You can only access the modified version of `Year` after the click occurs, i.e. inside the event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to change your program logic. Here we can use callbacks:

```js
// Your function
const ModifyYear = cb => {
  const button = document.querySelector("button");
  let Year = 2022;
  button.addEventListener("click", () => cb(Year+1));
}

// Call with callback function as parameter
ModifyYear(newYear => console.log(newYear));
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```